# An Inequality in Numerical Optimization

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading Jorge Nocedal and Sepher J. Wright's *Numerical Optimization* and stuck at an exercise 4.6 in chapter 4.

> The Canchy-Schwarz inequality states that for any vector $u$ and $v$, we have
>   $$|u^Tv|\leq(u^Tu)(v^Tv)$$
>   with equality only $u$ and $v$ are parallel. When $B$ is positive definite, use this inequality to show that
>   $$||g||^4\leq(g^TBg)(g^TB^{-1}g)$$
>   with equality only if $g$, $Bg$ and $B^{-1}g$ are parallel.

---

$B$ is positive definite if and only if $\forall g\in\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$, we have 
$$g^TBg>0$$
I have tried to prove this in some special cases:

- $B=A^TA$. It is easy to prove.
- When $B$ is symmetrical, we have a matrix $P$ to make $B=P^TP$. This is the case one.

However I have no idea in general case. There are some obstacles:

- How do we deal with $B^{-1}$?
- We cannot write $g^TBg$ as a form of norm.

Any advise is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Nocedal and Wright assume their positive definite matrices are symmetric.  Indeed, the statement is false without that assumption.  Try
$$ B = \pmatrix{1 & t\cr -t & 1\cr}$$